# Highlighting search results in Webmatrix webgrid

Tags: webmatrix, highlighting

I have recently started working with Webmatrix/razor (I am at the beginner's level). I have created a search page. In the search results, I would like to highlight the search terms. Can anyone help with this? Thank you.